# Video Sequence not fully loading in video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

When I drag the video file down from the files window, it brings in the video sequence and the audio with it, however, while all the audio loads in, the whole video wont, only about 80% ish of it would show in sequencer and there is more to load in because I watch the unedited footage and its right there. But it wont load into sequencer, I have tried hard cutting and deleting parts of the video sequence in case the amount was an issue, one small addition is the video is longer than the max amount of frames available for blender in the first place but this has never been an issue before as I have edited similar length videos as well.

Comment: The issue would be that the video is using a codec that blender can't decode. Can you get what codec is used by the video? What OS and blender version?

Comment: Codec is H.264 - NVENC (VBR), Windows 10, and Blender 2.77 I think, but why would codec restrict or stop the rest of the video sequence loading in, its pretty much only like another 20 mins missing, the rest loads in fine.

Comment: I thought none of the video was loading so expected a codec blender couldn't read.

Comment: It could be that Blender can't understand well video and audio frame rate so video and audio strip have different lengths, that happened in the past to me. But I can't understand how you could end with some missing part of a track... how long is your video, and what its fps?

Comment: The video is 03:11:00 (3 hours and 11 mins) long and is recorded at 30 fps, another minor detail which I didn't mention for some reason is that it is a game recording on screen, previous videos that I have edited have been just as long and have been recordings of gamming sessions and I have had no issues, the videos previously loading in completely but outside of the frame range, fro which I hard cut and deleted segments to make more room. But that isn't the case this time since the whole video isn't loading in.

Comment: A possible workaround might be to use FFmpeg to convert it to frames or chop it into smaller pieces.

Comment: I'm afraid FFmpeg is way outside of my area of expertise so I would really prefer another option, I have also just attempted to now load in another video file, recorded from another gaming session and I'm am still seeing the same problem. :(

Comment: After investigating, I have also now noticed that the first video is actually 26fps and the second one which I have started to edit is 20fps, despite the fact that I set it to record at 30fps, this was most likely due to performance issues overall as the gaming sesh was low fps from the start. But does the initial fps of the video have an effect when dragging the video file down to the sequence section, like translation issues etc... Its really starting to annoy me now. Please HELP.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue just now. You should use ffmpeg to re-encode the video, specifying a bitrate and forcing frames to be duplicated. This worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -c:a copy -r 30 -vsync cfr output.mp4
```

This will generate a huge file because it's not compressing the video at all; if space is an issue, you can play with the `-cfr` parameter, bringing it to 20 or so (higher numbers mean more compression).